# Sending email using jxl

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, jxl

I have a query in which I need to send email from my email id to a large group of people.

I have an excel file, which contains email address of people across the world with several domain names. I am reading these email and trying to send it but I get the error stating `"cannot send email"`

Probably I am using wrong **SMTP** names.

However when I send email to people in my domain, I am able to do so.

I want to have the same "From" address and different "To" address. Please let me know if this is possible.

**e.g From: address@somedomain.com
    To: address@other domain.com**

Regards

Bipul

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  Normally all the messages would be sent to **your** smtp server, which would forward them to the appropriate mail server for the recipient's domain.  Your smtp server may be rejecting some of the messages if it's not configured to allow you to relay messages outside your domain.  Possibly it won't let you do this because you [haven't authenticated to your mail server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay).

Comment: Could you please let me know a few lines of codes so that i can do this

Comment: Did you follow the link to the JavaMail FAQ?  [This entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpauth) will help.